# How to put condition from another page into a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a quiz game with HTML5 and JavaScript. My question is
how can I enable / disable a button in the main page, if a condition in *another* page is met.

For example, if the player in `stage 1` answers 4 of 6 answers correctly, then the button of `stage 2` is enabled in the main page.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="stage 1" onclick="if ( correct >= 4 ) from the other page"  />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="stage 2" disabled />
```

Comment: Is your application a Single Page Application? If not, you'll need to either use `localStorage`, a `SESSION`, or `cookies`.

Comment: no my application have more then 1 page.

Comment: if you can .give me an exemple.thanks

Comment: I can give you two examples: [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [**JavaScript cookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). As for `session` storage, it depends if you're using a back-end language, and which language that is.

Comment: localstorage exemple code thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you'll want to use some kind of server, or a form to get a value to assign it to a variable. Once it takes you to the new page you can simply pull the variable out of the server. Or store it in a session or a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript Cookies to do this, that way if the user has that cookie enabled, and they are visiting the homepage of your site you can check for that cookie and enable or disable the button.